# Tab Bar application inside a Navigation-based application

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an application which is designed to hold lots of instances of the same thing.

For example, amateur football teams can sign up and add their information to the app, and then browse through navigation controller/table-views to find their team amongst other teams.

Selecting a team would then open an instance of a view which would be tab-bar based.

The issue I'm having is the displaying of the tab bar icons. Other than that, it works perfectly.

There isn't any code involved, so my I can only really use images to explain.

Unfortunately I can't post images yet and can only post 2 links
Please look at the links:

http://s28.postimg.org/nxk8r1vst/IMG_3954.png

http://s28.postimg.org/6j00irynx/IMG_3955.png

When the tab-bar view is first opened in 1, you can see the icons aren't displayed correctly - the current tab is white tinted, the text of the other tab is default but the icon is white tinted. In links 2 and 3 they are highlighting and dimming properly BUT not picking up image tinting at all - i had set image tint to red to test it.

Image 4 is my storyboard for this. Doesn't seem to be anything wrong, as I said the navigation all works fine.

Apologies if this question isn't formatted properly. I haven't been able to find any answers and could really do with some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: You mention a "Image 4" and a "link 3".  What are the other two links or images supposed to show?

Comment: Apologies, I wrote that before I noticed I was only allowed 2 images links. Image 3 was just another image of the tab bar icons, and 4 was my storyboard

Comment: Ok - so, it turns out it was a silly mistake.

I implemented a side reveal menu a few weeks ago, and the instruction included this line to be added to AppDelegate.m:

    [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

that's all it was!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the images for the UITabBar in correct format:
It should be in png format and in the following size:

About 50 x 50 pixels (96 x 64 pixels maximum)
About 25 x 25 pixels (48 x 32 pixels maximum) for standard resolution

Also the image should be white on transparent.

Comment: Yep, in fact my tab bar images are exactly 25x25 and 50x50. But for this example I used the ones provided by apple in xcode to be sure it wasn't my images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that goes against an apple design directive.
Don't you mean several NavigationControllers one under each tab of a TabBarController i.e. NavigationControllers inside TabBarControllers and not the other way around?

By the images it looks like they are separate navigation controllers under distinct tabs